# Closed expressions for divergent series over Bernoulli numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series, bernoulli-numbers

**Motivation**

In a recent post ([Asymptotic behaviour of sums involving $k$, $\log(k)$ and $H_{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2891159/asymptotic-behaviour-of-sums-involving-k-logk-and-h-k#2891159)) I asked for the asymptotic behaviour of the sum

$$\sigma_{c}(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n H_{k} \log(k)\tag{1}$$

and I found that the constant in the asymptotic expression contained, among other known constants, the sum

$$\kappa_{c} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{B(2m)}{2m} \zeta'(2m)\\=\frac{1}{12} \zeta '(2)-\frac{\zeta '(4)}{120}+\frac{\zeta '(6)}{252}-+...\tag{2}$$

where $B(n)$ is the Bernoulli number of order $n$ and $\zeta'()$ is the derivative of the Riemann zeta function. This is a strongly divergent series, and I had to resort to the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sigma_{c}(n) - (\text{leading terms}))\tag{3}$$

for calculating the complete constant, a sum of known constants and $\kappa_{c}$, which, however, I could only use numerically.

Quite recently, however, in an answer to [Constant term in Stirling type formula for $\sum^N_{n=1} H_n \cdot \ln(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2898197/constant-term-in-stirling-type-formula-for-sumn-n-1-h-n-cdot-lnn), a consistent interpretation of the sum in (2) was given in terms of a convergent integral and the numerical value calculated.

**Questions**

This motivated me to ask for the values of similar divergent series, and for a proof of the interpretation of the following two examples:

$$\kappa_{d} :=\sum_{m=1}^\infty B(2m)\dot{=} \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{3}{2}\simeq 0.144934$$

and

$$\kappa_{e} :=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{B(2m)}{2m}\dot{=}\gamma -\frac{1}{2}\simeq 0.0772157 $$

Here $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\dot{=}$ means "is understood as" in the Ramanujan sense that $1+2+3+... \dot{=} -\frac{1}{12}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both, use the following formula, available as Gradshteyn&Rhyzik 3.411.2
$$\frac{B_{2n}}{2n} = (-1)^{n+1}\,2 \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}}{e^{2\pi\,x}-1}\,dx $$
Then a convergent integral for the second sum is derived by
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2n}}{2n} \,\dot{=} 
2 \int_0^\infty \frac{dx/x}{e^{2\pi\,x}-1}\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}x^{2n}
=2 \int_0^\infty \frac{dx\,x}{(x^2+1)(e^{2\pi\,x}-1)}.$$
Mathematica knows this integral, although G&R 3.415.1 can also be used:
$$ (A) \quad \int_0^\infty \frac{dx\,x}{(x^2+b^2)(e^{2\pi\,x}-1)} = 
\frac{1}{2}\big( \log{b} - \psi(b) - \frac{1}{2b} \big) $$
For $b=1$ we therefore have 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2n}}{2n} \,\dot{=} \,\gamma - \frac{1}{2} .$$
The other sum is similar,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_{2n} \,\dot{=} 
4 \int_0^\infty \frac{dx/x}{e^{2\pi\,x}-1}\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}n\,x^{2n}
=4 \int_0^\infty \frac{dx\,x}{(x^2+1)^2(e^{2\pi\,x}-1)}.$$
Differentiate eq. $(A)$ and set $b=1$ to find
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_{2n}\,\dot{=} \,\frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{3}{2} .$$

Comment: @ skbmoore Very good. I came from the "opposite direction" playing with Euler-Maclarin to solve the Basel problem and to calculate the asymptotics of $H_{n}$. (This was a nice exercise and I will present it as a self solution later; now I'm waiting for possible other solutions).